# Discrete 101: Validity of proof: Finding that p→q ∨ ¬r, q→p∧r, therefore p→r is invalid.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm sorry to bother with what apparently is a very easy Basic Logic question, but in my class'es notes there's an example that the professor probably explained in class:

```
Show that the following proof is invalid
p→(q∨¬r)
q→(p∧r)
therefore p→r
```

How would I go around showing this, and finding that something's wrong along the way? Truth tables?

Comment: @vadim123 I believe that due to the hierarchy/priority of actions that the professor taught us, if no parentheses are present, it would be p→(q∨¬r)

Comment: This is not a proof, it is an [inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference). You're being asked to prove that the inference is not valid, that is, you're being asked to prove that there are assignments of truth values to the propositional letters $p,q,$ and $r$ such that the premises ($p\to (q\lor \neg r)$ and $p\to (p\land r)$) are true, but the conclusion ($p\to r$) is false. One way to do it is by finding all valuations (assignments of truth values to the propositional letters) and then finding one that does the trick. Finding all valuations is the same as constructing truth tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to prove that proposition $a\to b$ is false is if $a$ is true and $b$ is false.  Hence, you must have $p$ true and $r$ false, by the conditions of the task you were set.  If $q$ were true, then $r$ would be true (by the second hypothesis), so we must have $q$ false.

Now verify that $\{p$ true, $q,r$ false$\}$ satisfy  both hypothesis and falsify the conclusion.

Comment: For $\{p$ true, $q,r$ false$\}$ both of the two hypotheses yield true. Therefore we have an instance where the hypotheses yield true but the proposition $p \to r$ yields false, so the whole thing has crumbled and is invalid?

Comment: Just so, you've got it.

Comment: Much obliged, mr. Vladimir.